# Haskell: monad stack bind with IO and []

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, io-monad

I have:

```
stuff :: IO [String]
doThings :: String -> IO [()]
```

and I want to

```
stuff >>= doThings
```

but my types are off. I want to do a lifted bind essentially but everything I try is subtly wrong.

Comment: `do xs <- stuff; mapM_ doThings xs`? What exactly are you trying to do. Also: `[()]` is a pretty useless type. Isn't an `Int` enough? Or can't you just have the type `String -> IO ()`?

Comment: Thanks! I changed `[()]` to `()` and used `mapM_`, it worked great!

Comment: You could keep `[()]` (assuming you have some reason to want that) by using `mapM`.  Notice the trailing `_` in Haskell typically means "ignore the result(s)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original types, you can do:

```
stuff >>= mapM_ doThings
```

This also works if you change doThings to have type `doThings :: String -> IO ()`

Answer (score 0):

If you've got lots of such functions, this is the textbook usecase of [`ListT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-List.html#t:ListT):

```
main = runListT $ do
  string <- ListT stuff
  ListT $ doThings string
```